# Passing the output of GetKeyboardLayout into LoadKeyboardLayout doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, language

**Question**

Why passing the output of `GetKeyboardLayout` (after formatting it to hex) into `LoadKeyboardLayout` doesn't work?

The docs for [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) say (bolded by me):

> **GetKeyboardLayout**
>
> Retrieves the active input locale identifier (formerly called the keyboard layout).
>
> **Return value**
>
> Type: HKL
>
> **The return value is the input locale identifier** for the thread. The
>   **low word contains a Language Identifier** for the input language and the
>   **high word contains a device handle** to the physical layout of the
>   keyboard.

And the docs for [`LoadKeyboardLayout`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayouta) say (bolded by me):

> **LoadKeyboardLayoutA**
>
> Loads a new input locale identifier (formerly called the keyboard layout) into the system.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> HKL LoadKeyboardLayoutA(
>   LPCSTR pwszKLID,
>   UINT   Flags
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `pwszKLID`
>
> Type: LPCTSTR
>
> **The name of the input locale identifier** to load. This name is a string
>   composed of the hexadecimal value of the **Language Identifier (low
>   word)** and a **device identifier (high word)**. For example, U.S. English
>   has a language identifier of 0x0409, so the primary U.S. English
>   layout is named "00000409". Variants of U.S. English layout (such as
>   the Dvorak layout) are named "00010409", "00020409", and so on.

The way I understand the bolded texts above is that passing the output of `GetKeyboardLayout` (after formatting it to hex) into `LoadKeyboardLayout` should just work, but it doesn't.

**Example**

Let's say that:

- Your default keyboard language is English US (can be anything else).
- Your current keyboard language is Russian (can be anything else).

Now, go ahead and run the following AutoHotKey script:

```
^1::run()

run() {
   currentKL := getCurrentKeyboardLayout()
   currentKL_hex := Format("{:#x}", currentKL)
   currentKL_hexsub := Format("{:08}", SubStr(currentKL_hex, 3))
   resultKL := Format("{:#x}", LoadKeyboardLayout(currentKL_hexsub))
}
getCurrentKeyboardLayout() {
   WinGet, winId,, A
   threadId := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "uint", winId, "uint", 0)
   inputLocaleIdentifierId := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint", threadId, "uint")
   Return inputLocaleIdentifierId
}
loadKeyboardLayout(inputLocaleIdentifierName) {
   KLF_ACTIVATE := 1
   inputLocaleIdentifierId := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", inputLocaleIdentifierName, "uint", KLF_ACTIVATE)
   Return inputLocaleIdentifierId
}
```

Printing `getKeyboardLayout`'s variables gives:

```
currentKL: 68748313        <-- Russian identifier,    int, output of GetKeyboardLayout 
currentKL_hex: 0x4190419   <-- Russian identifier,    hex
currentKL_hexsub: 04190419 <-- Russian identifier,    hex, input for LoadKeyboardLayout
resultKL: 0x4090409        <-- English US identifier, hex, output of LoadKeyboardLayout
```

Oops!
The fact that `resultKL` value is English US identifier and not Russian identifier means failure!
Here are the docs again (bolded by me):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the input locale
>   identifier corresponding to the name specified in pwszKLID. **If no
>   matching locale is available, the return value is the default language
>   of the system.**

**The Problem**

If we would have passed `00000419` (the identifier listed for Russian [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/available-language-packs-for-windows)) to `loadKeyboardLayout` instead of passing `04190419`, we would have get the desired result.

However, this won't work for other languages' layouts.

For example, let's take Hindi:

- If Hindi Traditional is the current keyboard layout, `getCurrentKeyboardLayout` outputs `0xf00c0439`. Passing this value (ommiting the `0x` prefix) to `loadKeyboardLayout` wouldn't work, but passing the [listed value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values) `00010439` will.
- If Hindi Phonetic is the current keyboard layout, `getCurrentKeyboardLayout` outputs `0x4090439`. Passing this value (ommiting the `0x` prefix) to `loadKeyboardLayout` wouldn't work, *and since Hindi Phoentic doesn't have a listed value, we can't get it from anywhere else*.

How can we load these (or other) layouts through `LoadKeyboardLayout` if it's not willing to work with the full identifier?

I guess I'm missing something fundamental, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the difference between the two cited docs:

While `GetKeyboardLayout` return-value is the input locale identifier, `LoadKeyboardLayout` input value should be the ***name*** of the input locale identifier.

`GetKeyboardLayout` returns a variable dubbed an "input locale identifier" of type `HKL` (which stands for "handle to a keyboard layout"), while `LoadKeyboardLayout` receives a parameter of type `LPCSTR` (named `pwszKLID`, where `pwsz` stands for a "pointer to wide-character string, zero-terminated" (that's Hungarian notation) and `KLID` stand for "keyboard layout identifier").

Now, to get a `KLID` from a `HKL`, we need to use `GetKeyboardLayoutName`. Sadly, it doesn't receives a `HKL` as parameter, but only retrieves the name of the currently active input locale identifier - but we can use this code I've found [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=28258):

```
getKLIDfromHKL(HKL) {
    VarSetCapacity(KLID, 8 * (A_IsUnicode ? 2 : 1))
    priorHKL := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", Ptr,DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", Ptr,0, UInt,0, Ptr), Ptr)
    if !DllCall("ActivateKeyboardLayout", Ptr, HKL, UInt,0) || 
       !DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutName", Ptr, &KLID)
        Return false
    DllCall("ActivateKeyboardLayout", Ptr, priorHKL, UInt,0)
    MsgBox, % StrGet(&KLID)
}
```

- *Note: we could actually only use the line with `DllCall("GetKeyboardLayoutName", Ptr, &KLID)` and change the language manually, but then this line should actually be called twice.*

So, keeping with the Russian example, `0x4190419` is the `HKL`, `00000419` is the `KLID`, and `04190419` is meaningless.

It worth citing here Michael Kaplan, who was a developer in the Windows International group. He had a post titled ["Why are the HKL and KLID of the keyboard different?"](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/04/17/409032.html). He answers:

> I actually get this question on a regular basis, believe it or not.
>
> People look at the two numbers, see the similarities, and then start
>   assuming they are the same
>
> The differences are not obvious if you install keyboards via the
>   `LoadKeyboardLayout` API [...] In that case,
>   the same LCID [*locale identifier*] is always used, and if the keyboard is one of the many
>   with `KLID` values like `00000409` or `00000407` then the `HKL` value will be
>   the same as `KLID`, further making people think they are the same.
>
> However, there are two times when they can and will be different:
>
> 1. Any time the `KLID` value is more than just the LANGID -- like `00010439`
>      for the Hindi Traditional keyboard layout or `0003041e` for the Thai
>      Pattachote (non-ShiftLock) keyboard layout, the `HKL` will have a high
>      word of the lower DWORD filled with different information.
> 2. [...]

- *Note: Take a look at two other related keyboard layout related posts by him, [Some keyboarding terms](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2004/11/27/270931.html) and the aptly named [How do I get the @!#$% name of the keyboard?](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2004/12/05/275231.html).*

Ok, what about Hindi, then?

Unfortunately, it turns out all that information still doesn't help! Specifically:

- Calling `getKLIDfromHKL(0xf00c0439)` (for Hindi Traditional) results in an error in the first call for `ActivateKeyboardLayout`, I'm not sure why.
- Calling `getKLIDfromHKL(0x4090439)` (for Hindi Phonetic) outputs `00000409`, which is the KLID for English.